# Executing the multiple instances of same package simultaneously through application?

Tags: ssis, msbi

I have a SSIS package which is executed from application. Can the same package be called simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can run package simultaneously, but keep in mind, this can sometimes lead to a deadlock on processed data (depending on the flow).

Package Property `MaxConcurrentExecutables` defines how many can remain running at once. The default is -1 and then it depends on the available cores (threads), but you can change it to whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, That could be done.
You can use Packages like classes and call multiple instances simultaneously in a parent package providing it with different set of parameters using a sequence container and call multiple instances of same package using Execute package task using same package connection.

Maximum number of tasks that could run simultaneously is dependent on number of cores in your machine.
Number of concurrent tasks= Number of cores +2